# Using CSS !important in ExtJS setFieldStyle()

Tags: html, css, extjs, extjs4

I'm trying to use the setFieldStyle on a textfield in ExtJS. I have another CSS sheet which sets the style on the background of the field as `white !important`. Unfortunately, I cannot modify this sheet so I need a way to update it in ExtJS.

I've tried using `setFieldStyle('background: #000000');` but as soon as I add `!important` it will not run the code.

Any ideas?

Comment: you should think to remove the `!important` from the previous style. Use `fieldCls` config instead.

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, I cannot modify the previous sheet. Thanks for the response though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

setFieldStyle will only set the style of input tag of the field, however the input and the field label are wrapped in another tag (usually a table) so using .getEl() will give you the outer element and you can set the style on that like this:

```
.getEl().setStyle('background', '#000000 !important')
```

Comment: This answer has been flagged has 'low quality'. Can you elaborate with a working example, an explanation for the OP ?

Comment: Thanks for this. I should have tried getEl() myself. Hopefully this might help someone else out there :)

Comment: getEl().setStyle will allow you to set the CSS attributes on the field element (the table tag that wraps the field and the field label in most cases), where as setFieldStyle will only set the style of input tag